# C# Hotkeys while holding Control

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying to add some hotkeys to my Window application so that if i press Ctrl+Q it will perform an action. I can't quite figure this out. I looked through stack overflow and MSDN but i can't find the answer i need. 
So this is what i currently have

xaml:

```
<Grid KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown" KeyUp="Grid_KeyUp">
    <Menu Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <MenuItem Name="MenuItemFile"  Header="File" >
            <MenuItem Name="CloseApp" Header="Close" Icon="" Click="CloseApp_Click" AutomationProperties.AcceleratorKey="Control L" InputGestureText="Ctrl+X"/>
        </MenuItem>
```

c#

```
private void Grid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl)
        {
            switch (e.Key)
            {
               case Key.L:
                  This.Close();
                  break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a key to a command in your XAML:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Q" Modifiers="Control" Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"/>
</Window.InputBindings>

<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" Executed="CloseCommandHandler"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

Then define what the command should do in your code-behind:

```
private void CloseCommandHandler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Or map it to a command in your ViewModel, if you're using the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do that by

```
private void Grid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Q && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: What namespace is that? because i have using System.Windows; and MSDN said it's part of using System.Windows.Input; but that didn't work. it can't find Modifier or Keys

Comment: [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.modifiers.aspx)

Comment: i got it to stop complaining about the keywords, but then the xaml sating saying that it was an invalid format and it wouldn't load. Icouldn't get the System.Windows.Forms to work

Answer (score 1):

This is in a different direction now, but WPF has Commands which can help you with this as well. You can define a `RoutedCommand` or `RoutedUICommand` and append EventHandlers to the `CanExecute` and `Executed` events. Commands can also have KeyBindings in combination with modification keys like `Ctrl` or `Shift`. This is particularly useful when you want to structure a bigger application.

Here are some details on [How to: Create a RoutedCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and an [overview about commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use ALT instead of CTRL? Is so, give this a try - it is built right in:

[Mnemonic Keys in WPF](http://csharptactics.blogspot.com/2011/08/mnemonic-keys-in-wpf.html)

Comment: Kinda. It's not while holding Alt. it works by tapping Alt (the cursor moves to the Menu) then i press L and it closes. But if i hold Alt and press L it does nothing

Comment: Yeah, it would have to involve multiple key strokes this way. One chord to open the menu, another to select the menu item.